# CSS кастомизация Radio

Tags: css3, html5, radio

Задача, сделать переключатель сортировки по исходящей или нисходящей. Использую спрайт файл для кастомизации элементов. Не могу убрать круглишки, чтобы остались только треугольники. Если я устанавливаю для класса:

```
.sort-toggle input[type="radio"] - display:none;
```

то не могу видеть переключатель:

[image: описание изображения]

```css
.sort-toggle {
  margin: 0 0 0 50px;
}

.sort-toggle label {
  display: none;
}

.sort-toggle input[type="radio"] {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sort-toggle-up:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  background: transparent url("../img/sprite.png") no-repeat;
  background-position: -77px -461px;
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
}

.sort-toggle-up:checked:before {
  background-position: -1px -461px;
}

.sort-toggle-up:hover:before {
  background-position: -40px -461px;
}

.sort-toggle-down::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  background: transparent url("../img/sprite.png") no-repeat;
  background-position: -77px -429px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.sort-toggle-down:checked:before {
  background-position: -1px -429px;
}

.sort-toggle-down:hover:before {
  background-position: -40px -429px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sort-toggle">
  <input class="sort-toggle-up" id="sort-up" type="radio" name="radio-sort" checked>
  <label for="sort-up">Сортировка по возрастанию</label>
  <input class="sort-toggle-down" id="sort-down" type="radio" name="radio-sort">
  <label for="sort-down">Сортировка по убыванию</label>
</div>
```

Comment: По ссылке пример, как стилизировать инпут для твоего случая http://dimox.name/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-using-css-only/ Я пробовал пример из "Теги чекбокса и радиокнопки находятся перед тегом label", комментируешь все box-shadow, border'ы и все кругляшки исчезают.

Comment: Задай `input-ам`  - `display:none;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за Ваши отзывы. В конце концов запилил все сам. Код получился рабочий, можете CTRL+C и CTRL+V и все заработает. Не знаю как вставить внизу своего сообщения кнопку Выполнить код.

```css
.visually-hidden {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sort-toggle input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.sort-toggle label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sort-toggle input[type="radio"]+label.sort-toggle-up svg,
.sort-toggle input[type="radio"]+label.sort-toggle-down svg {
  width: 11px;
  height: 10px;
  fill: #c5c5c5;
}

.sort-toggle input[type="radio"]:checked+label.sort-toggle-up svg,
.sort-toggle input[type="radio"]:checked+label.sort-toggle-down svg {
  fill: red;
}

.sort-toggle input[type="radio"]:hover+label.sort-toggle-up svg,
.sort-toggle input[type="radio"]:hover+label.sort-toggle-down svg {
  fill: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="sort-toggle">
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" id="sort-up" name="radio-sort">
  <label for="sort-up" class="sort-toggle-up">
            <span class="visually-hidden">Сортировка по возрастанию</span>
            <svg><polygon points="5.5,0 0,10 11,10 " /></svg>
        </label>

  <input type="radio" id="sort-down" name="radio-sort">
  <label for="sort-down" class="sort-toggle-down">
            <span class="visually-hidden">Сортировка по убыванию</span>
            <svg><polyline points="5.5,10 0,0 11,0 " /></svg>  
        </label>
</div>
```